# Type information in placement new

Tags: c++

I have a placement new operator that, quite predictably, allocates memory from a pool. However, I also need to know the object type to set up some meta fields. I could pass it as a second argument to placement new as a string, but since I specify the type when calling new anyway, isn't there any way to get it implicitly?

E.g. I could do this:

```
void* operator new(size_t count, Pool* pool, const char* type)
{
  return pool->alloc(count, type); // type is used to associate metadata with the allocated chunk
}
Car* car = new(pool, "Car") Car(...);
```

But can't I do something like this?

```
template<class T>
void* operator new(size_t count, Pool* pool)
{
  return pool->alloc(count, typeid(T).name());
}
Car* car = new(pool) Car(...);
```

Comment: It's ambiguous - the compiler won't be able to figure out what type you want for that template. Also, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish overall here but your solution doesn't look ideal.

Comment: Technically, `typeid(T).name()` is allowed to return the same string for different types.  Though that would be a poor implementation.  When you need to arrange things by C++ type, use a `std::type_index`.

Comment: You need some kind of type system to keep track of May be you can use GType system

Comment: @aschepler: I've actually raised this as a question a while ago, and settled on `name()` anyway for various reasons.

Comment: Also, I can't see how it would be ambiguous, if I wrote `new(pool) Car(...)` surely it should know that I'm constructing an object of `Car`. My use case is binding Lua objects, I allocate memory via `lua_newuserdata`, and need to bind an appropriate metatable to it. If I could index metatables by type instead of implicitly specifying their name, the code would be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

No, sorry.  Except for member allocator functions, which only work for class types you control, C++ neither uses the class type to select an `operator new` function nor provides any standard way for an `operator new` function to determine the type of the calling new-expression (if any).

You could give your `Pool` class a template member function to take care of both allocating and constructing:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T* Pool::create(Args&& ... args) {
    void* ptr = alloc(count, typeid(T).name());
    try {
        return ::new(ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch (...) {
        dealloc(ptr);
        throw;
    }
}

    // ...
    Car* car = pool->create<Car>(vroom);
```

(Other comments about stuff you might already know: Remember to implement a matching placement-delete in case a class constructor throws an exception.  Consider making an [Allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) interface for compatibility with the standard library.)

Comment: I've considered this, but it seems VS2010 doesn't support it.